# What are the variables I need to consider when planting my Eidelweiss?

Tags: plant-health, flowers, plant-recommendations, plant-care

I've done a fair bit of research to avoid people doing work for me but I'm still a bit confused. I have purchased three Eidelweiss that have arrived a week ahead of schedule and I'm woefully unprepared.

I do know that mulch is used during the winter to simulate its native condition but..
I live in Florida and it's pretty warm this time of the year. I know this flower is hardy but I have questions in regard to planting them. 
Since they are well past germination, I'm under the impression these should be planted in the ground and I need to manage conditions such as acidity of ph and drainage. What are the best ways to achieve this if they are to be planted in the ground ?

I've included an image of each plant.

One: Leontopodium Alpinium
[image]

Two: Leontopodium Alpinum Matterhorn (Rep too low to post 3 links)
[image]

I've also discovered a few bits of conflicting information such as allowing this plant to take in sun through a window versus don't you dare window sun soak!

How long can this plant grow in this pot? Should it be planted immediately? And how do I prepare my soil for these beautiful flowers?

You'll have to forgive my ignorance as I'm aware I've picked a pretty peculiar flower to start with.

By the way, are these flowers in decent shape?

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: An alpine plant in Florida? Strange world. On contrary, I want to plant tropical flowers in alpine environment.

Comment: Ha yes very peculiar but there is a reason,  it holds great sentimental value. I need to maintain this plant for a few weeks before it reaches its new home up north, which I am aware iis a much better climate for these plants.

Comment: A few weeks? Don't plant, but keep it in the pot. Plant at the final destination, please!

Comment: Thank you for your replies!! I'll try to add it Sue! Stephie, I will take heed of your advice, appreciate it! But why exactly does it need to be planted in the final destination? Does this cause the plant distress ? Also how often should I water the plant, I want to be real careful not to overwater.

Answer (score 4):

I had two edelweiss plants which I obtained from commercially available seeds and I kept them indoors for two winters and that's why they stayed in a rosette leaf state.

The plant flowers only if it has stayed outdoors the previous winter. Also, one important thing to look out for is the colour of the leaves. If they are green, you must add some lime and the leaves will slowly develop a silvery shine - I used some powdered chalk dissolved in water.

I could have kept them outdoors in the winter, but I was very curious about what would happen if kept indoors. Sadly, I have recently lost them due to me not informing the person that took care of them while I was away that overwatering should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

[care of Edelweiss](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/edelweiss/edelweiss-in-the-garden.htm)This plant is one of the most collected and most prized.  It most certainly can grow below alpine status.  I've seen huge clumps of them growing in zone 4 sea level!!  The most important thing this plant needs is drainage.  Hates too much water and wet feet.  It needs a bit of babying until you are able to create its new home and acclimize it correctly before transplanting.  Even if it is just from indoors to out of doors.

Keep them right there in those pots for the winter.  Keep them brightly lit but NOT in direct sun.  Try to not use tap water as those chemicals in our tap water are horrid for any plant and animal to include us but Edelweiss is very sensitive to crap water.  Allow to dry out a bit, never completely. Lift the bottom of those pots off their surface to improve drainage, do not add rock or gravel between the soil and the drainage hole and for the winter keep them in ONE place.

If you are planning to plant them in your garden wait until the weather is predictable.  Start hardening them off with a few hours out of doors NOT IN DIRECT SUN and increase the time spent out doors when they get a chance to endure a few days at a time at the same time allotment.  They will do just fine left in the pots they now reside for this entire winter.  Acclimate them then transplant in the garden early spring or transplant in a pot, clay, shallower than tall and allow to settle in.  Very very light fertilizer!  Osmocote using half the amount recommended will be fine every 4 to 5 months.

These look like they've decided to go into dormancy.  The important thing to know is where these plants were growing before you brought them home!  Were they out of doors in a nursery or were they indoors?  Immediately, go find out if you don't know by calling that nursery.  This is probably the most important thing to know, we need to know to help you acclimize even in Florida.  Most of my recommendation here is based on far colder climes.

Before you transplant (next spring) let us know what soil you have in your garden is it raised or flat and if you plant in pots ONLY USE BAGGED POTTING SOIL.  Preferably for 'cactus' type plants.

pH would obviously be towards alkaline.  pH 6.5 to 7.2. Do you have a way to test pH?  Try at least 2 store bought methods.  You can raise the pH by adding lime if the pH is too low of course but wait until spring.  Be nice to see what the pH of the soil those plants came in is...There are all kinds of pH testers but store bought pH indicators aren't perfect.  For fun, get a pH test of the soil in the garden where you are imagining replanting them.

You know, Florida is just a different world than the one I am familiar.  Have you got (of course you must) a cooperative extension service from a Florida University?  I would definitely contact them for information. Talk to the Master Gardeners!!  They understand your soils, climate, rain and how to grow Edelweiss in Florida best!!  Nothing like experience and sadly I've only experience growing in ALPINE CONDITIONS!! Grins!!  Lucky you.  Keep them in these containers out of direct sun, slightly on the dry side but always some moisture and don't use tap water!!  Get a couple of gallons of distilled/spring water to water them with.  You might be able to plant them in the garden sooner than 'SPRING'.  Get the pH settled, where you want to plant them and talk to the people who live and breathe in Florida!!

Comment: And flowers are only a small part of the beauty of any plant.  Cut the flowers off whenever you want, they only take energy away from the plant especially a newbie plant in a newbie environment.